# how to apply all color spaces at one by one and save it image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
read = cv.imread(image_path)
applying_color_spaces = cv.cvtColor(read, g)
```

at `g` position, I want to apply all color spaces one by one and write image to desktop.

Comment: what do you expect? Writing a HSV image to disk as if it was a BGR image does not make much sense. Can you tell about what you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: You can only pass one conversion code there.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple snippet to get you started. I used two lists:

- The *first* list contains all the color space conversions.
- The *second* list contains the corresponding strings to be used for saving the images.

**Code:**

```
import os
import cv2

read = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\leaf.JPG', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

color_name = ['gray', 'HSV', 'LAB', 'YCrCb']
color_spaces = [cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb]

for name, i in zip(color_name, color_spaces):
    res = cv2.cvtColor(read, i)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop', name + '.jpg'), res)
```